# Parent/child reference: hidden setter, public getter

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to mimic the parent/child behaviour of `UIView`s for my own objects. I have two objects `A` and `B` that reference each other. `A` is considered to be the parent of `B`. `A` and `B` are in two different files.

```
class A {
  private(set) var child: B?

  func setChild(child: B) {
    self.child = child
    child.parent = self
  }
}

class B {
  weak var parent: A? 
}

let a = A()
let b = B()
a.setChild(b)
b.parent // a
b.parent = nil // shouldn't be possible!
```

The thing is: I don't want to be able to modify the `parent` property of `B` outside the `setChild` method of `A`, so it is only possible to set the parent/child relationship from `A`.

`UIView`s have the same behaviour with the `superview` property.
As long as a view hasn't been added to a superview, its `superview` property remains `nil`. `superview` is read-only and cannot be modified. Adding a subview with `addSubview` modifies its `superview`.

Modifying the access control of `parent` to private would allow the read-only behaviour but would disallow me from setting it from `setChild` in `A`.

Does that make sense? How can this be achieve in Swift? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you doing this in a playground?

Comment: No, in an iOS app. But testing in Playground.

Comment: This isn't really mimicking UIView. The superview of a UIView is also a UIView. You're making it an unrelated class, and then putting it in a separate file. The best solution is to not put it in a separate file. If you must (it's maintained by some other party for instance), then B should be a subclass of A, as with UIView; then R.Menke's solution works.

Comment: Swift is not like ObjC. There is no reason to have a 1:1 mapping of files to types.

Comment: Sure, but that is part of the problem. I can't have all my code in one file :)

Comment: @RobNapier is right though, it's not mimicking `UIView`. My question involves 2 classes.

Comment: I've actually put whole frameworks in a single file. It's not nearly as crazy as it sounds and has many benefits (especially simplifying code reuse). But it's almost certainly not necessary. The Swift model encourages *related* (what C++ would call friend) types to be in the same file.

Comment: @RobNapier I agree on that. I just think it gets out of control for large classes/structs/enums. All-in-one-file just seems wrong (unless you can't to things differently, like in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If `A` and `B` are in the same file**

```
class B {
    private(set) weak var parent: A? 
}


let a = A()
let b = B()
a.setChild(b)
b.parent // a
b.parent = nil // is impossible
```

---

**UIView-like structure:**

```
class Hierarchy {

    private(set) weak var parent : Hierarchy?
    private(set) var children: [Hierarchy] = []

    func addSub(item:Hierarchy) {
        item.parent = self
        children.append(item)
    }
}

class A : Hierarchy {

}

class B : Hierarchy {

}


// put this in another file
func test() {

    let a = A()
    let b = B()

    a.addSub(b)
    b.parent = nil // impossible

}
```

Comment: How would `A` be able to set the `parent` property of `B` if its private? Both `A` and `B` are in separate Swift files.

Comment: I have, really. I didn't make `parent` private since I can't see how `A` would be able to set it if its private. That's part of the problem I'm trying to solve. Since `A` and `B` are in different files, making `parent` private would make it invisible from `A` file. That's why I made `parent` public. In other words: How do you make `parent` private, but still having `A` allowed to set it?

Comment: Agreed then, that's why I'm asking if you guys can think of a Swifty/OOP way to do it :)

Comment: @NicolasB. there isn't. Best not to go against how everything works. That is the opposite of a "Swifty" solution

Comment: @NicolasB. updated answer. It is not pretty but it works. If both `A` and `B` inherit from a class that implements the entire child/parent logic you will be able to achieve what you want. I will however involve a lot of `casting`

Comment: Note that "Swifty" and "OOP" are generally opposed concepts. Swift in general hates subclasses. Much of its type system falls apart when you start inheriting.

Comment: @RobNapier yes, I am hoping A and B do not need inheritance from another class. This pattern is easy with subclassing, less so in a protocol fashion.

Comment: @RobNapier "OOP" in the sense of "manipulating objects", no necessarily involving inheritance. Swift is object oriented - it manipulates objects. Note that I'm not requiring any (or talking about) subclasses in my original post. `A` and `B` can be root objects, confirming to Swift best practices.